# How to test string for certain symbols? (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a compiler for my own language as part of a university project and have come across this problem when writing a module to determine the type of input in a string (alpha, numeric, delimiter etc.).

```
private static void readChar(ref string sentence, ref int inputType)
    {
        foreach (char test in sentence)
        {

            if ((test.CompareTo("|") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("*") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("/") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("+") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("-") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("@") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("#") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("$") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("%") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("^") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("&") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("(") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo(")") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo(",") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("`") == 0) |
                (test.CompareTo("=") == 0))
            {
                inputType = 5; // delimiter
            }
            else
            {
                if ((test.CompareTo("0") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("1") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("2") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("3") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("4") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("5") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("6") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("7") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("8") == 0) |
                    (test.CompareTo("9") == 0))
                {
                    inputType = 3; // numeric              
                } // end if compareTo Numeric
                else
                {
                    if ((test.CompareTo(" ") == 0)) inputType = 6; //space

                    else
                        if ((test.CompareTo(";") == 0)) inputType = 7;  //semicolon          
                        else
                        {
                            inputType = 1; // alpha
                        } // end alpha
                } // end else

            } // end if
        }

    } // end readChar
```

When I reach the first if statement it returns this error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object must be of type Char.

I am not sure how to solve this as I am using char for the test and do not know which object the error is referring to.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate any help ^^

Comment: You can use `Char.IsDigit('9');` and you can use double '||', a single '|' makes no sense.

Comment: Why is the string parameter `ref`? And what use is it for updating the `ref int` parameter very many times in a loop? Is anything trying to read this int variable just as fast? It does not seem sound.

Comment: One idea is to `switch (test) { ... }` and then have a switch block (with many `case` labels on each block) for each "input type" (`5`, `3`, `6`, etc.).

Comment: Right, that does make more sense. Thanks for the suggestions. New to C# still so just getting used to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything written between double quotes `"asdf..."` is a *string* literal.
If you want a char literal you use single quotes `'a'`

```
private static void readChar(ref string sentence, ref int inputType)
{
    foreach (char test in sentence)
    {

        if ((test.CompareTo('|') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('*') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('/') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('+') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('-') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('@') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('#') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('$') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('%') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('^') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('&') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('(') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo(')') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo(',') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('`') == 0) |
            (test.CompareTo('=') == 0))
        {
            ......
```

Comment: It is better to use `==` between two `char` values here. `.CompareTo` is for general sorting, not equality checks.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you used quotation marks attributed to strings. Use single quotes.

```
String s = "String";
char c = 'c';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick suggestion:

```
private static void ReadChar(string sentence, ref int inputType)
{
    foreach (char test in sentence) {
        if ("|*/+-@#$%^&(),`=".Contains(test)) {
            inputType = 5;
        } // delimiter
        else if (Char.IsDigit(test)) {
            inputType = 3;
        } // numeric              
        else if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(test)) {
            inputType = 6;
        } // space
        else if (test == ';') {
            inputType = 7;
        } // semicolon          
        else {
            inputType = 1;
        } // end alpha
    }
}
```

Comment: ``"|*/+-@#$%^&(),`=".Contains(test)`` goes through Linq (and uses the fact that `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`), so do not forget to have a `using System.Linq;` directive with this solution. To avoid Linq, you can say ``"|*/+-@#$%^&(),`=".IndexOf(test) != -1``, but Linq is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `CompareTo` methos accepts a **char** to compare. You are passing in a **string**.

 use single quotes for `'char'`
 double quotes for a `"string"`